# exclude button from page layout in package doesn't seem to work

Tags: managed-package, page-layout

I have a managed package where I've updated the standard page layout for a custom object to exclude the New button from a related list like so:

```
<relatedLists>
        <excludeButtons>New</excludeButtons>
```

After the package is installed in a test org however the New button is there. Is it not possible to exclude these when deploying a package?

Once the package is installed I can manually go into the page layout and remove it again.

Comment: Review James' answer. He's probably correct, so no idea why he deleted it. In short, page layouts are not "updateable", only "createable", which means that whatever the layout looks like once installed is what the customer will have until they (or you) change it. On a fresh install, the button should not appear.

Comment: Yes totally agree its spot on, i have sent him a message to add it back... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In managed packages, you can add new page layouts, but you cannot upgrade existing page layouts, including layouts that are part of the package..

More info on what you can create and upgrade here: https://org62.my.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf

From the docs:

[image: ISV guide screenshot]

Comment: @Phil B Hopefully that answers your question on what can / cannot be done via managed packages. If not, I probably read the question wrong.

Comment: thanks, yeah I think this answers my question so if I install this package with the buttons removed in a fresh org instead of an upgrade the buttons should be excluded correct?

Comment: Your page layout should be okay if you're installing in a fresh org, yes.  Only one way to find out, though!